# When removing last element, jquery removes first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove last div from the html DOM, when i click remove last button.

Here is jquery code:

```
$('#remove-last').click(function(){
    $('#ed').last().remove();
});
```

Here is my html

```
<div id="ed">LaLa</div>
<div id="ed">LaLa</div>
<div id="ed">LaLa</div>
```

But the jquery code removes first element, and I need to remove last?? What is wrong here?

The divs and id are generated dynamical by jQuery, (what peace of code are before function that removes div) then user press ad new field button.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**... use class instead of ID

Comment: Change `id` attribute name with `class`; change js code to `$('.ed:last').remove();` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`id`s need to be unique, therfore jquery just returns a single `dom element` (wrapped by jq of course), when you use the `id selector`. And the last element of that is also the first, since it's only one dom element. If you want to fit multiple dom elements into one semantic group, you should use a `class` instead, like this:

```
<div class="ed">LaLa</div>
<div class="ed">LaLa</div>
<div class="ed">LaLa</div>
```

which can be accessed through jQuery using the `class selector` `.classname`:

```
$('.ed').last().remove();
```